# Can an Observer Distinguish between Unruh Effect and Hawking Radiation by Measuring Temperature?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation, equivalence-principle, unruh-effect

In Unruh effect, the temperature of background appears to be proportional to acceleration. On the other hand, the temperature of a black hole is inversely proportional to its mass.

If the two effects have the same origin as mentioned in

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/259342/85274

temperature in both must include the same proportionality to acceleration and to gravitational acceleration, respectively.

According to equivalence principle, an observer hovering above the horizon of a black hole is equivalent to an observer who accelerates somewhere far from any massive body. But he can measure the thermal radiation, use the formulas for the two effects and infer in which situation he is.

Does it imply that there *is* distinction between the situations, from an observer's point of view, or is something wrong with my argument?

Comment: *"But he can measure the thermal radiation, use the formulas for the two effects and infer in which situation he is."* How?

Comment: @DanielSank: How to measure temperature or how to infer?

Comment: You must have a *very* good thermometer if you can measure the temperature of the Hawking radiation of a stellar black hole.

Comment: @PM2Ring: of course! everything is supposed to be possible in principle here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably assuming an uniformly accelerating observer, then no, because [The Unruh temperature has the same form as the Hawking temperature TH = 
ħg
/
2πckB
 of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect).

Assuming an inertial observer makes a difference. An inertial observer doesn't see Unruh Radiation, but far away from a Black Hole will see Hawking radiation.