# Ways to derive black-body radiation in Unruh effect

Tags: thermal-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect, big-list

I know two ways to derive black-body radiation in Unruh effect and they are:

1. Using Bogoliubov coefficients (N. D. Birrell and Paul Davies)
2. Using Page approximation (David J. Toms and Leonard Parker)

Are there other ways to derive this effect (for example using Hamiltonian diagonalization maybe)?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of various techniques? Because there are in fact many ways to derive the effect. Such “big-list” questions are discouraged here.

Comment: @A.V.S.since the answer will involve "big-list", will it be alright if this question is changed to a wiki. Also, I was not able to find an exhaustive list of the methods using google or physics journal so that was the reason I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unruh effect can be considered as a special case of Hawking radiation (See the beautiful answer of Motl to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259338/is-hawking-radiation-really-the-same-as-unruh-radiation) question). Then finding ways to discover the Hawking effect gives you ways to infer the Unruh radiation existence.

Three lovely and strongly physical derivations of the Hawking effect:

1) Cancelling gravitational anomalies https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0502074

2) Avoiding equivalence principle violations https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5564

3) Hawking's derivation using the imaginary time trick https://hapax.github.io/physics/imaginary-time/