# Deriving Hawking temperature "from" Unruh effect and their relation

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, unruh-effect

Let me recall some basic computational facts (the meaning of which I am trying to understand).

1. In flat space, an adapted coordinate $(\tau, \xi)$ associated with an observer with constant proper acceleration $\alpha$ is
   $$
   ct = \frac{c^2}{\alpha} e^{\alpha \xi/c^2} \sinh \big(  \frac{\alpha}{c}\tau  \big), \quad
   x = \frac{c^2}{\alpha} e^{\alpha \xi/c^2}\sinh \big(  \frac{\alpha}{c}\tau  \big) \ .
   $$
   Quantizing the free real scalar theory in $(t, x)$ and $(\tau, \xi)$ leads to an Unruh temperature
   $$
   T_\text{Unruh} = \frac{\hbar \alpha}{2\pi c k_B} \ .
   $$
2. The Schwarzschild coordinate $(t,r, \theta, \varphi)$ can be transformed to a $(t, \xi, \theta, \varphi)$ coordinate, such that
   $$
   r = r_s + \xi \ .
   $$
   Near the horizon, $\xi/r_s$ is small, and the metric takes the form
   $$
   ds^2 = - \frac{\xi}{r_s}c^2 dt^2 + \frac{r_s}{\xi}d\xi^2 + ds^2_{\theta, \varphi} + \text{higher $\xi$ terms} \ .
   $$
   One can further transform it to a "flat coordinate"
   $$
   cT = 2r_s e^{\frac{\xi}{2r_s}} \sinh \frac{c}{2r_s}t, \qquad
   X = 2r_s e^{\frac{\xi}{2r_s}} \cosh \frac{c}{2r_s}t \ .
   $$
   The near horizon metric now reads $ds^2 = -c^2 dT^2 + dX^2 + ds^2_{\theta, \varphi}$.

Now, if I "compare" the $(t, x) \to (\tau, \xi)$ transformation with the $(T, X) \to (t, \xi)$ transformation in the two bullet points, I would say that there is an "effective proper acceleration"
$$
\frac{c}{2r_s} = \frac{\alpha_\text{BH}}{c}, \qquad
\alpha_\text{BH} = \frac{c^2}{2r_s} = \frac{c^4}{4GM} = \text{finite surface gravity} \ .
$$
Translating this acceleration to a "Unruh temperature", one recovers the standard formula
$$
T = \frac{\hbar \alpha_\text{BH}}{2\pi c k} = \frac{\hbar c^3}{8\pi G k M} \ .
$$

Here are my confusions

1. Does the $\alpha_\text{BH}$ have the meaning of "proper acceleration" of something measured by some actual local comoving observer near the horizon?
2. The above computation is performed in the **near horizon limit**, leading to the standard Hawking temperature. However, accrding to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22942/intensity-of-hawking-radiation-for-different-observers-relative-to-a-black-hole), this is the temperature measured by a **faraway observer**. I wonder how to understand this "near horizon" and "faraway" relation? How do we know if some computation performed at some location (e.g. near horizon) = something measured by a faraway observer?