# Interior Hawking radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The Hawking effect is induced by the causal horizon of a black hole, which separates the interior and exterior modes such that asymptotic observers at infinity see thermal radiation flux. What can we say about the physics of interior modes? Can we think of them as interior Hawking radiation at some temperature? Do any observers behind the horizon see thermal radiation?

Note that I'm not asking about a quantum gravity question, but rather just a QFT-on-curved-spacetime question. (Any relevant references would be useful.)

Comment: Semi-classically one has to assume that a freefalling observer inside the event Horizon will experience a rapidly rising radiation temperature... assuming that there is such a place as the inside of the event horizon. That is, at best, a semi-classical concept in itself. It may be correct or it may not be, so we are using a semi-classical concept to support the physics of a semi-classically modeled system. If we do this for superconductivity, then there is no superconductivity. If we do this for the stability of matter, then there is no matter. So why is it supposed to work for black holes?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22942/123208 "a freefalling observer sees negligible Hawking radiation"

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm more concerned with an interior observer. Does any interior observer see Hawking radiation?

Comment: From  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/187925/123208 "The falling observer always sees the apparent horizon in front of them until they reach the singularity in a finite proper time."