# Is Hawking radiation possible for all massive objects (based on new research)?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

So a few years ago, looking at the answer to this question the answer was no and that there needed to be an event horizon for hawking radiation to arise and that it is not purely curvature that causes it.

However according to https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2023/06/230602115051.htm, there is evidence that all large objects not just black holes will evaporate.

So what may be the cause of this? In the case of black holes it makes sense that the black hole just becomes less steep of a gravitational well and that energy goes into the photons in Hawking radiation. But what about with neutron stars, where would the energy come from?

Comment: [The technical paper on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18521).

Comment: I am skeptical about the conclusion you have from the article. The latter tries to unify the Schwinger effect with the gravitational pair production, which differs from Hawking radiation. They indeed say that their "local approach could imply
that also mass configurations without a global event horizon would radiate and eventually decay.", but to me, this seems to be a far-reaching overinterpretation of their work. Moreover, their view of the quantum vacuum seems to be outdated: virtual particles do not populate the vacuum, they are internal lines in Feynman diagrams.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux -Please have patience with existence:  The description of virtual particles as an abstraction is extremely interesting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative energy particle effect on observable object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767280/168783). Summarizing the answers in that post, there is some doubt on whether the paper is correct