# Will Hawking radiation violate baryon number conservation around gravitating bodies other than black holes?

Tags: planets, stars, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, protons

Numberous articles discussing a recent  [research paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.130.221502) suggest that even stars and planets will eventually radiate away their mass like hawking radiation. My question is will this violate baryon number conservation.

Comment: Do you have the links to these papers? If so, then please provide them in your question.

Comment: I just linked to a published research paper that many articles discusses as sugesting a curvature of space is needed rather than an event horizon.

Comment: The arXiv link to the paper is:  [Gravitational Pair Production and Black Hole Evaporation (2023)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18521): "We present a new avenue to black hole evaporation using a heat-kernel approach. ...our pair production mechanism itself does not explicitly make use of the presence of a black hole event horizon."

Answer (score 6):

These papers have been discussed in previous questions such as [Negative energy particle effect on observable object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767280/168783) and a bit in [Is Hawking radiation possible for all massive objects (based on new research)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769747/168783). In summary, many (and I would guess most) people in QFTCS do not agree with the results of the paper. A horizon *is* necessary for the existence of Hawking radiation.

Assuming, though, that the paper is right, then I should mention Hawking radiation violates baryon number conservation in black holes due to the no-hair theorem, which ensures knowledge of what the black hole is made of is lost. Collapsing a cloud of neutrons or a cloud of photons into a black hole leads to identical objects, as long as the starting matter options had the same masses and angular momenta. This argument does not hold for planets of stars, and hence I see no reason for how or why baryon number conservation would be broken.